# How can I execute an action after each end of thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust

In Rust, I would like to do multiple tasks in parallel and when each task finishes, I would like to do another task handled by the main process.
I know that tasks will finish at different timings, and I don't want to wait for all the tasks to do the next task.
I've tried doing multiple threads handled by the main process but I have to wait for all the threads to finish before doing another action or maybe I did not understand.

```
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
```

How can I manage to do a task handled by the main process after each end of threads without blocking the whole main thread?

Here is a diagram to explain what I want to do :

[image: Diagram]

If i'm not clear or if you have a better idea to handle my problem, don't mind to tell me!

Comment: You'll have to check [`is_finished`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.is_finished) in a loop, and call `join` and do the `action_after_end` when it first returns true for a given handle.

Comment: Or have the main thread block on a mpsc channel, to which each thread sends a message just before it terminates.  Saves the main thread from busy-polling but requires cooperation from the child threads.

Comment: For safety the channel could be embedded in a structure which would automatically send a message on `Drop`, that way it's hard to mess up when code gets refactored.

Comment: An alternative would be to use... async, the parent would `spawn_blocking` the children, then it could use an async wait / select (maybe an async stream / iterator?) on both and handle them as they finish, letting the runtime handle the synchronisation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I found a solution that combines the answers of PitaJ and eggyal.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72493340/7953565
I didn't really understand Masklinn's answers, maybe I still have some things to learn first...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example how to implement this using `FuturesUnordered` and Tokio:

```
use futures::{stream::FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::{time::Duration, future::ready};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    tasks.push(some_task(1000));
    tasks.push(some_task(2000));
    tasks.push(some_task(500));
    tasks.push(some_task(1500));
    tasks.for_each(|result| {
        println!("Task finished after {} ms.", result);
        ready(())
    }).await;
}

async fn some_task(delay_ms: u64) -> u64 {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay_ms)).await;
    delay_ms
}
```

If you run this code, you can see that the closure passed to `for_each()` is executed immediately whenever a task finishes, even though they don't finish in the order they were created.

Note that Tokio takes care of scheduling the tasks to different threads for you. By default, there will be one thread per CPU core.

To compile this, you need to add this to your Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

If you want to add some proper error propagation, the code becomes only slightly more complex – most of the added code is for the custom error type:

```
use futures::{stream::FuturesUnordered, TryStreamExt};
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::{time::Duration, future::ready};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    let tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    tasks.push(some_task(1000));
    tasks.push(some_task(2000));
    tasks.push(some_task(500));
    tasks.push(some_task(1500));
    tasks.try_for_each(|result| {
        println!("Task finished after {} ms.", result);
        ready(Ok(()))
    }).await
}

async fn some_task(delay_ms: u64) -> Result<u64, MyError> {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay_ms)).await;
    Ok(delay_ms)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError {}

impl std::fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "MyError occurred")
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for MyError {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this well explained example, I came up with a solution found after posting this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/72493340/7953565
Yours seems to be more readable and comprehensive so I'll give it a try !

Comment: @Rtxx The other answer you linked implements this based on `std::thread`, while this answer uses the whole async machinery, which is a completely different beast, and comes with complexities of its own. I think it's totally worth learning, since it's versatile and will benefit you for many different programming tasks, but it might not be the fastest approach if you are not yet familiar with async programming.